# User Meta stuff

Tags: users, user-meta

Ok I am trying to make a page the list user meta.

http://pastebin.com/rw1t7Mgp

The part I am stuck on is

`$our_children = get_user_meta ($user_id,"our_children");`

it is a meta field with an array in it.

`a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"Name";s:6:"Elisha";s:3:"Age";s:2:"13";}}`

How do I display the data in that array?

`//foreach ( $our_children as $children ) {
            echo '<tr><td>'. $our_children-> Name .'</td><<td>'. $our_children-> Age .'</td></tr>';
            //}`

Doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few PHP issues preventing output-

1. it appears your foreach is commented out with `//`.
2. you do `foreach( $our_children as $children )`, but then you use `$our_children` instead of `$children` inside the foreach.
3. `$children->Age` is for accessing an object's property, but what you have here is an array, so it should be `$children['Age']`

-

```
foreach ( $our_children as $children ) {
    echo '<tr><td>'. $children['Name'] .'</td><td>'. $children['Age'] .'</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Also, even if `$children` was an object, the space in `$children-> Age` and `$children-> Name` would cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress stores arrays in the database as serialized data.  Once you have retrieved it, you can use php's [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) if you're sure of the format or WordPress's [maybe_unserialize](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize).

Note that in your example you're expecting an object, that won't *always* be the case, it depends on how the data was stored originally.

Comment: it should be noted that `get_user_meta` itself uses `maybe_unserialize`, if you're getting serialized data back from that function there's something wrong.